# How can I stop the script when I run the game on my own computer?

Tags: python, authentication, oauth-2.0

hi friends i am trying to make a steam hour bot. I'm running this bot on my ubuntu system like this on "screen -S idle python3 xxx.py" . What I want to do is to close the screen  when I enter a game on my computer, I want the bot to close itself.. The code I use is below.

```
import logging
from steam.client import SteamClient
from steam.enums import EResult
from steam.enums import EFriendRelationship, EPersonaState, EChatEntryType
from steam.client import user
# setup logging
logging.basicConfig(format="%(asctime)s | %(message)s", level=logging.INFO)
LOG = logging.getLogger()

client = SteamClient()
client.set_credential_location(".")  # where to store sentry files and other stuff
server_ip=client.current_server_addr
@client.on("error")
def handle_error(result):
    LOG.info("Logon result: %s", repr(result))

@client.on("channel_secured")
def send_login():
    if client.relogin_available:
        client.relogin()

@client.on("connected")
def handle_connected():
    LOG.info("Connected to %s", client.current_server_addr)
@client.on("reconnect")
def handle_reconnect(delay):
    LOG.info("Out...")
    LOG.info("Reconnect in %ds...", delay)
    client.logout()
    raise SystemExit

@client.on("disconnected")
def handle_disconnect():
    LOG.info("Disconnected.")
    client.disconnect()


    if client.relogin_available:
        LOG.info("Reconnecting...")
        client.reconnect(maxdelay=30)


@client.on("logged_on")
def handle_after_logon():
    LOG.info("-"*30)
    LOG.info("Logged on as: %s", client.user.name)
    LOG.info("Community profile: %s", client.steam_id.community_url)
    LOG.info("Last logon: %s", client.user.last_logon)
    LOG.info("Last logoff: %s", client.user.last_logoff)
    LOG.info("-"*30)
    LOG.info("Press ^C to exit")


# main bit
LOG.info("Persistent logon recipe")
LOG.info("-"*30)

try:
    result = client.cli_login("username","password")
    if result != EResult.OK:
        LOG.info("Failed to login: %s" % repr(result))
        raise SystemExit

    else:
        client.get_web_session("English")
        client.games_played([730])
        client.change_status(persona_state=EPersonaState.Online, player_name='xxx')
        client.run_forever()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    if client.connected:
        LOG.info("Logout")
        client.logout()
```

library documentation i use;
https://steam.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/steam.client.html#steam.client.SteamClient.set_credential_location
When I enter the game from steam on my own computer, it catches my connection and continues to scirpt I want it to close.

Comment: maybe create script which simply kill your bot and then it runs your game.

Comment: @furas Everything will be resolved if I can check that I entered the game from my own computer.

Comment: @furas
 if (result == EResult.LoggedInElsewhere):
        client.logout()
        os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGKILL)
I put such control, but it doesn't work.

Comment: do you get any error or what ? Do you run it in separated script ? If you run it in separated script then `os.getpid()` gives you PID for new script, not for script which you want to kill. Some programs after start save PID in file, and remove this file at the end - and then other program may get is PID from file to kill it (and if there is no file then it is know that program doesn't run yet or was closed earlier)